# Running Tensorboard in Jupyter in Sagemaker: this site can't be reached

Tags: tensorflow, localhost, jupyter, tensorboard, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to run tensorboard from my Jupyter notebook in Sagemaker. The below is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import datetime, os

%load_ext tensorboard
logs_base_dir = "./logs"
os.makedirs(logs_base_dir)

!tensorboard --logdir=data/ --host localhost --port=8080
```

The output I get looks fine:
`TensorBoard 1.14.0 at http://localhost:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)`
but when I click on the link, I'm taken to a page with ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Does anyone have suggestions about what to try next? Thanks so much!

Tensorflow: 1.14
Python: 2

Comment: what link are you trying to open ?

Comment: the one generated by Sagemaker (http://localhost:8080/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments it seems to me that you are trying to open the wrong URL. If I understand you question, you are not running in a local environment, so you can not open `localhost`. The right URL for `sagemaker` from the docs is `https://<notebook instance hostname>/proxy/6006/`